# Netbeans Shortcut to Open File

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, openfiledialog, classname

I remember seeing someone use a shortcut in NetBeans to open a dialog similar to phpStrom that can open files based on class names or is it file name. whats that?

[image]

Comment: Some kind of search file feature in NetBeans.

Comment: Updated my answer, found the plugin.

Comment: Alt+Shift+O opens the native file search

Comment: `alt-shift-O` - Thats what @faisalbhagat said down bellow.
Thats the shortcut. Please up vote his comment.

Comment: @jiew-meng Please consider changing the selected answer, it should be just Alt+Shift+O, not that really long answer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

*Updated*

I'm fairly certain you are referring to the "Quick File Chooser" plugin. As someone else points out, though, there are several other candidates. I list them below...

***The Quick File Chooser Plugin***:

By default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> opens the *Open Project* dialog, and once the plugin is installed, you will get the dialog pictured here automatically:

[image: Quick File Chooser - Open Project Dialog]

(The Quick File Chooser plugin replaces the default open project dialog with its own.)

When opening a file with the Quick File Chooser plugin, you see this:

[image: Quick File Chooser - Open File Dialog]

I did not find that the plugin was able to open based on a class name.

Quick File Chooser is available through the [NetBeans Plugin Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16203/quick-file-chooser). You can also install it directly from within NetBeans versions 7.1 and 7.3 if you have the "Plugin Portal" Update Center configured. (See the bottom of this answer for instructions.)

***NetBeans Core (no plugin)***

By default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> opens the *Open Project* dialog, and *without* the QFC plugin, you will get the default dialog:

[image: default Open Project dialog (Windows)]

The default *Open File* dialog is this:

[image: default Open File dialog (Windows)]

The *Open File* dialog does not have a keyboard shortcut by default, but you can easily add it:

- Click on *Tools*, then *Options*, then on the *Keymap* icon in the tool bar of the dialog.
- In *Search:* type *"Open Fi"* and you should see *"Open File..."* in the *Actions* list.
- Double click on the *Shortcut* box for that entry, and select an appropriate shortcut (either by pressing the key combination, or by selecting it from the drop-down).
- Click *OK*.

*The Go To... Dialogs*:

The *Go To...* dialogs are provided by core NetBeans, and are available even if the QFC plugin is installed (the QFC plugin does not override them).

The *Go To File* dialog is <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>.

[image]

*Go To Type*: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, appears to list classes, variables, and all sorts of stuff.

[image]

*Go To Symbol*: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

[image]

For PHP projects, *Go To Type* and *Go To Symbol* appear to list the same set.  As mentioned, all of these are available on the *Navigate* menu.

**Installing Quick File Chooser from the Plugin Portal Update Center**

In NetBeans:

- Click on *Tools*, then *Plugins*
- Go to the *Settings* tab
- Ensure that the *"Plugin Portal"* is listed in *Configuration of Update Centers* and checked as *Active*. If it is not listed, click *Add*, give it an appropriate name, and the URL is http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/7.3/catalog.xml.gz for versions 7.3.x. (In the URL replace the "7.3" with, e.g., "7.2" or "7.1" if you are using an older version of NetBeans.)
- Click on the *Available Plugins* tab.
- Click on *Reload Catalog* just to be sure you have the latest contents.
- In *Search:* type *"Quick"*. That should be enough to get it listed by itself (or at least on a short list).
- Click on the check box under the *Install* column, and then click on the *Install* button down below.

Comment: i used ctrl+shift+at ie@ to open file;

Comment: In my NetBeans with the "NetBeans" Keymap profile CTRL-SHIFT-@ (which is really CTRL-SHIFT-2) selects the file that is currently open in the editor over in the "Files" tab.

Comment: +10000.  Holy crap been using NB for a few years and never knew about CTRL SHIFT O.  THANKS!!!

Comment: This is just not the answer. alt+shift+o that's it.

Answer (score 43):

to open a file based on its name
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: this answer should be the accepted answer, simple, straight to the point

Comment: Agreed. This is the real answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
THIS is the right aswer! Those guys up there didint understand the question.

Comment: I think so too. Best answer. It does not loose me to waste my time

Comment: On mac it's CTRL+SHIFT+O

Comment: Best answer saved my day

Answer (score 6):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to search files based on their 'Class Name'.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution for this would be
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

This will open the file open dialog box, now you can browse through the files and open which-ever file you want or if you have the complete path to that file just paste it in the text-field which says "File name:" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open this dialog for Java classes. 
I don't know if this is also valid for PHP though.

If you just want to open *some* file based on its name, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

**Edit**:
Both actions are available in the `Navigate` menu.

Comment: It works in OSX. Do the same job as Command + P in SublimeText.

Answer (score 1):

This is old and pretty much answered, but you may also try [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16495/open-file-fast) - works for all up to 8.2:

Comment: Yup, that plugin does the job.

Comment: I realize this is a bit older, but I just found this plugin as well. Have you found a way to copy/paste into that dialog box? For some reason it won't let me do so

Answer (score 1):

My shortcuts different from answers above (don't know why).

To me its `Alt + Shift + L`, Or `Navigate->"Go to File"`.

To search by type its `Alt + Shift + O` or `Navigate-> "Go to Type"` (you can see the shortcut in front of it)

It did not require me to install any plugins BTW. Netbeans version: 8.2

Answer (score 0):

The best way to search and open file in netbeans:

Press ctrl + o and type file name you are looking for, it will search in current projects and list matching files thn you can select file and open.

Comment: It doesn't answer exactly the question because he wants to open any file but the shortcut you showed could be useful to open Java files

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use **open file fast** plugin. it got two matching modes, smart (like in textmate) and exact.

Comment: I realize this is a bit older, but I just found this plugin as well. Have you found a way to copy/paste into that dialog box? For some reason it won't let me do so

Answer (score 0):

The best way to open the file without any plugins is to use `Alt` + `Shift` + `O`, then netbeans will offer all the available files with your given keywords.

I do also believe the answer from @faisalbhagat must be the accepted answer as @Thor mentioned above!