# Goto jsp page in NetBeans

Tags: spring, jsp, netbeans, ide

I work with Spring framework and have a lot of lines in *.java*:

```
new ModelAndView("/reports/distribution", map);
```

and in *dispatcher-servlet.xml*:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
</bean>
```

I think that this info is enough for goto file *PROJ-ROOT/src/main/jsp/reports/distribution.jsp* from java code.

Is there any standard command or extension for NetBeans with implementation of such command?

Comment: Sorry, i do not get it. Why don't you use "open file" and paste "distribution.jsp" into the search field?

Comment: seems that you forget to note that you use the "Quick FileChooser" plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Ben* suggested for goto JSP file feature "Quick FileChooser" plug-in can be used.

But this solution isn't perfect as use need select and copy JSP file name...

- [Netbeans Shortcut to Open File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573483/netbeans-shortcut-to-open-file)
- http://blog.anorgan.com/2012/10/14/quick-file-opening-in-netbeans/
- http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/16495/open-file-fast